# Trigger jQuery Script on Link Click (not on page load)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

My apologies in advance for asking what I'm sure is a totally newbie question related to jQuery.

I am trying to configure the "jQuery Feature Tour" by Zurb : http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_joyride_feature_tour_plugin

By default, they have things setup so that the tour begins on page load, but this is not what I want.

I want to have a link labeled "Start Tour" that, when clicked, will start the tour.

The default code they provide is this:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
      autoStart : true,
      postStepCallback : function (index, tip) {
      if (index == 2) {
        $(this).joyride('set_li', false, 1);
      }
    },
    modal:true,
    expose: true
    });
  });
```

Obviously I can set autoStart to "false".

But, even then I don't know how to trigger the script to run upon clicking another link.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
        autoStart : true,
        postStepCallback : function (index, tip) {
            if (index == 2) {
                $(this).joyride('set_li', false, 1);
            }
        },
        modal:true,
        expose: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks tymeJV! Appreciate the quick reply. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#LinkId').click(onClick);

function onClick() {
    // This function will execute when the link with id='LinkId' is clicked.
    // You can put the code to start the tour inside this function.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I appreciate the quick reply. I'll try that right now.